# using webp to reduce size of files for React app

Tags: reactjs, webp

I ran [Lighthouse](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/overview/) against my React app and among its suggestions was to serve one of my large `jpg` images in a next-gen format such as `webp`. So I got the cwebp conversion tool [executable](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/precompiled) and ran it against the image.

Following the [docs](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/using), I used the `cwebp` command to create a *.webp* file. Per my command parameters, the resulting file size was reduced, as expected. As an experiment, I then changed the *.webp* extension to *.jpg* (to match my other image files) and it opened fine.

I then re-tried my `cwebp` command, but with the output file set to *.jpg*. That also seemed to work. Smaller file sizes, and the jpg opened without issue.

So is there any issue with either 1) changing a *.webp* file extension to *.jpg* and using it in a React app as if it's a jpg file; or 2) simply using the `cwebp` command to output files with extension *.jpg*?

I'm guessing this "direct to jpg" approach is not valid, as the `webp` docs don't mention it.

(Note: I tried the documented approach of using `dwebp` to convert the resulting *.webp* files back to *.png*, but the resulting files ended up being significantly *larger* than their initial size.)